# The application from IntelliJ Idea 2018.1 to Glassfish 5.0.1 is not deployed

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, glassfish

Help me please! I cannot deploy application from IDE. When I run application, glassfish was starting but cannot deploy application. 
I am trying set up password to domain1 but still the same.

Idea2018.1, MacOs 10.13.5, Glassfish 5.0.1, JDK 1.8.0.141

Nothing errors but:
No errors except:
Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.AuthenticationInfo.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V Stack trace: com.intellij.javaee.process.common.JavaeeProcessUtilException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.AuthenticationInfo.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V at com.intellij.javaee.process.common.MethodInvocator.invoke(MethodInvocator.java:47) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.processRequest(JavaeeProcess.java:112) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.run(JavaeeProcess.java:52) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.main(JavaeeProcess.java:31) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.AuthenticationInfo.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V at com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish31Agent.getConnection(Glassfish31Agent.java:36) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish3AgentBase.invoke(Glassfish3AgentBase.java:183) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish3AgentBase.doConnect(Glassfish3AgentBase.java:39) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase$1.doJob(SimpleAgentBase.java:17) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase$1.doJob(SimpleAgentBase.java:13) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentJob.perform(SimpleAgentJob.java:12) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase.connect(SimpleAgentBase.java:25) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.intellij.javaee.process.common.MethodInvocator.invoke(MethodInvocator.java:41) ... 3 more

Comment: The intelij connector may not be updated yet.  Will 5.0 or a 4 do?

Comment: Maybe... I don't know.. But with tomcat everything ok. I used Glassfish 5.0.1 ver (it's latest version).

Comment: Use an older version of glass fish.

Comment: @AndreiRomanov see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194181

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, 5.0.1 sort of last version...  I achieved that GlassFish starts, but IntelliJ does not deploy application. I do it necessary manually. About debugging I am silent...

Comment: @AndreiRomanov Glassfish 5.0.1 was changed and the intellij code needs to be updated before it will work again.  This is what the youtrack link is about.  Use 5.0 instead or Glassfish 4.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, thank you very much. I done this and it helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish 5.0.1 broke the IntelliJ adapter (some API change probably).  Until that is fixed by JetBrains use an older version.  5.0 or 4 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I already have opened an issue on Jetbrains with lots of informations: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194181

The last functional version was GF 5.0.1 (build 20171121).

What they changed to broken the IDEA plugin is here: https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/commit/aeca5223f4ede5ea4423497c4f83e80f9cfb7185#diff-7bc38f41e6b87d51ceff9f429e1d6375

They change the contract of constructor from String -> char[] to secure passwords not using JVM's String pool.

Answer (score 1):

I am developer responsible for IDEA GlassFish integration. As a general rule of thumb, we are not supporting the nightly streams of the application servers before they reach at least Release candidate stage.

I have requested GF team to rollback the change at https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/pull/22336.

Until then please consider switching to the corresponding Payara builds, they reported to have this backward compatibility issue addressed.

If the issue can't be addressed in GlassFish before their RC, I will add version-specific workaround in IDEA code.

If you absolutely must work with this specific version of GF, ping me at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194181, and I will prepare the un-official plugin build that work with this specific GF version (but will fail with any of the previous GF builds).